# Chrome Devtools Snippets run continuously.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I no longer have the ability to execute scripts in the snippets section of my chrome dev tools. I can write scripts with no issue, but the run button is not available to click, instead it is constantly a pause button. This occurs in any and all new and old files in my snippets section.

If you click the pause script button, it opens up a file with the name VM#### (#s being numbers that increase each time based on how long it has been between clicking pause. Eg: the file will be called VM3162 when clicking pause. then upon closing the file, resuming the script and pausing again, it will be VM3168).

Inside this file are just three lines

```
!!(
    Object.keys(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__._renderers).length || window.React
)
```

I have the react dev tools extension installed, but have uninstalled it with no effect.

I've searched for this code in both google and StackOverflow, but have had no luck finding a post with a similar issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I have suddenly run into this as well.